# How does devise know what table you want form data written to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Here is devise' 'sign up' view (new.html.erb).

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I have a table called 'users' where I want the data to go. When I make an account on my system, the data is written to my users table, and it all works perfectly. But how does devise know I want the data to go to 'users'?

Though I am beginning to get a grasp on rails, how do the symbols :password, :email, ect equate to database input? Is this something to do with devise' source code, rather than rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define:

```
devise_for :users
```

You tell devise to define a `Devise::Mapping` instance.

When you go to `users/sign_in` devise get this mapping instance with `users` part of the URL.

This mapping object is used to get an `User` instance:

```
def resource
  instance_variable_get(:"@#{resource_name}")
end
```

where `resource_name` is `mapping.name`

You can check `DeviseController` class which uses `Mapping` class in [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/devise/frames)